# Android webservice practice?

Tags: android, web-services

I currently have a database and want my android apps to access a webservice and then access the database.

Currently i'm thinking of using either option. ksoap with asp.net that uses .asmx files created and also a page using asp.net that response.write json output. May i know which should be the better choice?

Comment: I prefer Java Servlet or PHP for Web Services

Comment: REST webservice is a better option when it comes to android. I would personally recommend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the JSON route. Android has an API for parsing JSON built-in, and JSON format is more efficient in terms of size.

Aside from basic XML parsers, there's nothing built into android to handle SOAP, and from what I've seen, 3rd party offerings are limited.

Comment: +1 as an Android developer I would much rather access a REST webservice that gives me a JSON output than SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.The service is in php but should be simple to adapt ti asp.net.
http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/php-android